# std::list::remove_if goes crazy if combined with a generic lambda

Tags: gcc, lambda, clang, c++14, language-lawyer

I found a problem that I guess is due to a bug in GCC.
Anyway, before opening an issue, I would like to be sure.

Consider the code below:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<list>

template<typename U>
struct S {
    using FT = void(*)(); 
    struct T { FT func; };

    template<typename> 
    static void f() { } 

    std::list<T> l{ { &f<int> }, { &f<char> } };

    void run() {  
        l.remove_if([](const T &t) { return t.func == &f<int>; }); // (1)
        l.remove_if([](const auto &t) { return t.func == &f<int>; }); // (2)
    }
};

int main() {
    S<void> s;
    s.run();
}
```

clang v3.9 [compiles both *(1)* and *(2)*](https://godbolt.org/g/I7wdmG) as expected.
GCC v6.2 [compiles *(1)*](https://godbolt.org/g/jaJtZo), but it [doesn't compile *(2)*](https://godbolt.org/g/2vMl5o).
The returned error is:

> error: 'f' was not declared in this scope

Moreover, note that GCC [compiles *(2)*](https://godbolt.org/g/eqwx1C) if it is modified as it follows:

```
l.remove_if([](const auto &t) { return t.func == &S<U>::f<int>; }); // (2)
```

As far as I know, using an `const auto &` instead of `const T &` should not alter the behavior in this case.

Is it a bug of GCC?

Comment: I'm wondering in what scope the compiler generates the class representing the *generic* lambda: file-scope, class-scope, function-scope (as local-class, but that does *not* support function template as member)?

Comment: From [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#4) - _The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression_. I would say `S<U>`, that's why I think that's a bug and it should _see_ the declaration of `f`.

Comment: @Nawaz Maybe [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#10) is even more appropriate - _The reaching scope of a local lambda expression is the set of enclosing scopes up to and including the innermost enclosing function and its parameters_?

Comment: @skypjack hmm if you remove outer template (`typename <class U>`) it will also get compiled...

Comment: I'm guessing that the presence of `T` in the signature invokes some of the 'dependent name' semantics, but I'll let an actual language-lawyer write the answer...

Comment: @W.F. Yeah, of course, I noticed it. The minimal, working example is really a *minimal* one!! I did my best. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack was just wondering if it is not because of the fact that you need to use `template` keyword before referring to nested templates... but apparently not the case here...

Comment: @skypjack One more observation: `l.remove_if([x=&f<int>](const auto &t) { return t.func == x; });` works... so the problem affects only the block of body...

Comment: removing the unknown of the `std` from the equation: https://godbolt.org/g/OuoxwA

Comment: it looks like a bug. If `f` is not templated it finds `f` from `&f`

Comment: @bolov `f` has not to be captured. Does this confirm that's a bug of GCC? Note that clang compiles as well also with your snippet.

Comment: I would say most likely a bug. Would take a lot of standard quotes to confirm this though.

Comment: @bolov While waiting for a language-lawyer, [let's see what they say](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77792). :-)

Comment: When dealing with a possible compiler bug, minimize it. The MCVE for this requires no `std::list`, nor `remove_if`, nor the includes. (And why is `<algorithm>` even there in the first place?)

Comment: @T.C. Why do you think I didn't try to minimize it? The best effort of someone could be inevitably different from the best effort of someone else. Isn't it one of the reasons for which even SO exists?

Comment: A good rule of thumb when minimizing for this kind of problems is "avoid including headers if at all possible". The preprocessed source file of your code sample takes up a whopping 17k lines on my system.

Comment: @T.C. By reading your comment it comes to my mind that it would help a (community?) Q/A about how to write a good C++ MVCE, if one doesn't exist already. Of course, [there is the _official_ how-to](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but even your rule of thumb made on the fly is better!! Would it be too much an _opinion-based_ one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per **[expr.prim.lambda]**:

> 8 - [...] [For] purposes of name lookup (3.4) [...] the compound-statement is considered in the context of the lambda-expression. [...]

[MCVE](https://godbolt.org/g/EG9Zv0):

```
template<int>
struct S {
  template<int> static void f();
  S() { void(*g)(char) = [](auto) { f<0>; }; }
};
S<0> s;
```

Hoisting the compound-statement to the context of the lambda-expression gives a clearly valid program:

```
template<int>
struct S {
  template<int> static void f();
  S() { f<0>; }
};
S<0> s;
```

So yes, this is a bug in gcc.